# How to generate a sitemap only with http and no https

Tags: http, https, sitemap

Lately my website starded to suport https and http aswell, no redirects from one to other and i generated a new sitemap.xml using:

http://www.web-site-map.com/xml_sitemap.php

And this is on the google faq:

```
 Q: My site has both "http" and "https" versions of URLs. Do I need to list both?

No. Please list only one version of a URL in your Sitemaps. Including multiple versions of URLs may result in incomplete crawling of your site.
```

And now i got a lot of duplicated links like:

```
<url>

<loc>http://www.xxxxx.com/jogar-buraco-online.php</loc>

<changefreq>daily</changefreq>

<priority>0.85</priority>

</url>
```

and

```
<url>

<loc>https://www.xxxxx.com/jogar-buraco-online.php</loc>

<changefreq>daily</changefreq>

<priority>0.69</priority>

</url>
```

http and https, how do i generate http separated of https or should i just delete all https one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Free tools like that are great to get you started but lack the finer control needed to do what you require.

It is a pretty big SEO no no to have both https and http versions of your site available, Google can think you have duplicate content and doesn't know which one it should give preference to.

I would suggest putting a redirect on for http to https - if you Google your webserver and http to https redirects you will find all the resources you need (for example, "Apache http to https redirects").

If you do this then the free tool you were using should only pick up https and not http. Which would solve your issue.

If there is some reason why you need both I would suggest using a sitemap generator that works with your CMS or framework.